# Can one characterize the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces?

Tags: ct.category-theory, linear-algebra, abelian-categories

Let $K$ be a field. Does the category of finitely generated $K$-modules have a nice characterization, for example as the unique abelian category satisfying a certain simple condition? For example, we know that:

1. Every short exact sequence is split.
2. The Euler characteristic of every bounded exact sequence is zero.

Are either of those enough to characterize the category?

Comment: Do you emphasis on how to characterize "finite dimensional" in a categorical way?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118246/characterising-categories-of-vector-spaces

Comment: What do you mean by the Euler characteristic of a complex of objects in an abelian category? Do you mean the alternating sum of the images in the Grothendieck group, and if so, isn't this always equal to zero?

Comment: I'm also not sure how you expect to recover the field $K$. Are we secretly talking about $K$-linear categories or are you happy to characterize these categories as $K$ runs over all fields?

Comment: $K$ could be recovered as the center of the category.

Comment: See my question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/118246/characterising-categories-of-vector-spaces, which has a very satisfactory answer.

Comment: @Fernando: that's not what I mean. The wording of the OP's question suggests that he wants simple conditions that pin down $\text{FinVect}_K$ for *fixed* $K$, and that seems unlikely to me unless we explicitly code in $K$, e.g. by working with $K$-linear categories.

Comment: I see your point. Still you can add the simple condition that the center of the category be your fixed $K$. I only see a problem in the definition of Euler characteristic. If you take it to be the element in $K_0$ represented by a complex then any exact sequence would go to $0$ by definition, and that's like assuming 2 is always true.

Comment: ... or you can add the condition that the center of your category, which in general is a commutative ring, is an algebra over the ground field $K$. That amounts to the category being $K$-linear. I think where speaking about the same thing, indeed.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is no, and an easy counterexample is provided by the category of finite-dimensional modules over a division algebra such as the quaternions. Of course this is not a very good example because you can easily add small modifications to your question to get rid of it. This category is for instance not symmetric monoidal, unlike vector spaces over a field. As Oskar points out, there is an already answered question in MO which gives a positive answer to your question under somewhat different conditions. You'll like to look at it. I warn you that your Euler characteristic condition may be complicated to state in an abstract setting.